# How to extract a Sound envelope from a .wav file using Python?

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing

I have a sound file which comprise of the instrumental sound. What I want to do is examine the each note of the instrument by extracting from the audio file. Can I use python for doing this or any other open source software that you can recommend to do this. I got the waveform using Audacity. I have attached the image of the sound file and red mark indicate the portion to be extracted. Starting and ending of the envelope. (Only single instrument is played in the audio file).
[image: [Waveform of the sound file]

Comment: What does red mark mean? It's ambiguous because another red mark should exist between the 3rd and the 4th.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. I have manually added the red mark in order to explain where to cut. I want to cut till that mark. So I can have different files with individual envelope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you want is usually called an envelope detector or [envelope follower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_detector#Audio). Maybe try out the [pyo project](https://code.google.com/p/pyo/) for this. The [analysis module](https://code.google.com/p/pyo/source/browse/trunk/pyolib/analysis.py?r=949) has a few envelope followers available.

Edit: I appear to have misunderstood your question from the title. You want to actually split the notes? I would extract the envelope, then split based on a threshold.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will check for the pyo project. Yes I want to split the notes. rather more specific a Tabla (Indian Percussion Instrument)Bols.